# Form of Wieferich primes?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

http://library.uwinnipeg.ca/people/dobson/mathematics/Wieferich_prime_theorems.html
states Gallardo's result on Wieferich primes:

A prime $q = 2p + 1$ with $p$ prime and $p ≡ 3 \mod 4$ cannot be a Wieferich prime,

Do you know any other form which can not be a Wieferich prime?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither a Mersenne prime $p=2^q-1$ nor a Fermat prime $p=2^{2^n}+1$ can be a Wieferich prime. More generally, any prime whose binary expansion has all its $1'$s lying in arithmetic progression of positions cannot be a Wieferich prime, see [here](https://books.google.at/books?id=ZXjHKPS1LEAC&pg=PA64&lpg=PA64&dq=on+primes+which+cannot+be+Wieferich+prime&source=bl&ots=m9TqbzM9Qb&sig=tPW-lseT2H4rKY9WZHWMvycohis&hl=de&sa=X&ei=Dof0VK2OKs7JOZuqgPAM&ved=0CF8Q6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=on%20primes%20which%20cannot%20be%20Wieferich%20prime&f=false).